# Avoid unintentional reference for a no-longer used for-loop variable

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I want my VSCode to warn of an `out-of-scope' reference for a for-loop variable. That is, sort of

```py
for element_id, element in dict.items():
    # some processing

for element in dict.values():
    print(element_id) # typo for element.id
```

Here in the second loop I refer to `element_id` of the finished loop by mistake. Since I have made this kind of typos many times, I want some linter to prohibit this kind of reference. I know PyCharm (and maybe IntelliJ too?) points it out. Are there any relevant extensions or modules available on VSCode? Currently I use `flake8` (and `mypy`) as a linter.

Comment: This is strictly not a programming question. You are asking about an extension or a third party module which is off-topic on SO.